# Supertest port Already in use even after setting setting Jest to "runInBand"

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, jestjs, supertest

I am new to unit testing. So, I am writing a node application and having issues testing the route.

I am using Supertest and Jest and I have tried all answers I can find.

I keep getting the error

```
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 5000
```

Here is my **package.json**

```
"test": "jest --verbose --watchAll --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit --coverage"
```

I have also tried maxWorkers=1
`

Here is my **index.js**

```
app.use("/api/v1", clinicRoutes);

let PORT;

process.env.STATUS === "production"
  ? (PORT = process.env.PROD_PORT)
  : (PORT = process.env.DEV_PORT);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  logger.info(
    `app is running in ${process.env.STATUS} mode, listening on port ${PORT}`
  );
});
```

Here is my **index.test.js**

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../index");


describe("Test the clinic search API", () => {
  test("It should respond with a list of clinics", async () => {
    const response = await request(app)
      .post("/api/v1/search")
      .send({
        name: "Scratch",
        state: "California",
        availableFrom: "01:00",
        availableTo: "23:00",
      })
      .set("Accept", "application/json");

    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    expect(response.body).toHaveProperty("data");
    expect(Array.isArray(response.body.data)).toBe(true);
    expect(response.body.data[0]).toHaveProperty("name");
    expect(response.body.data[0]).toHaveProperty("state");
    expect(response.body.data[0]).toHaveProperty("availability");
    expect(response.body.data[0].availability).toHaveProperty("from");
    expect(response.body.data[0].availability).toHaveProperty("to");
  });
});
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: Give the _app_ to Supertest, without listening, then it can assign a free port for you. Also note that having two ports you switch between based on the environment "status" seems a bit fussy - why not just have one `PORT` and set that to an appropriate value _in the environment_?

Comment: The port sounds like a good idea actually. I will fix that.

However, I don't understand what you mean by Giving the app to Supertest without listening? 

2 questions: 1) Does that mean I can only test route in Dev mode? I can't put it in a pipeline? 2). It is not returning said value because app isn't listening

Comment: I mean split up the [_app_](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/main/server/app.js) and the [_server_](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/main/server/server.js), so that the [tests](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/main/server/app.test.js) can use the former directly. Then you're not blocked on a specific port being available.